# Is HTML5 considered as a programming language?

Tags: html

as far as i know programming language is something that instructs to do processes to come up with desirable output.. like it can do computations, logical.. etc. 
now, with the new features of html in html5 which can include other computations or other processes and functions.. can it be considered as programming language? or still it is a mark up language? justify.

please help. Response will be highly appreciated. Another knowledge to ponder.

Comment: It's a **markup** language

Comment: can you explain further why?

Comment: Mr. Alien, tnx.. i didn't notice

Comment: The usual way to solve these kinds of problems is to take the definition of *programming langauge*, take the defintion of *HTML5* and compare these two.  At what point in this process are you stuck?